# How to set network interface between VMs using ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a problem related to networking in VirtualBox and I need your help. In the figure, I want to create a small topology which contains a Ubuntu VM (Blue box) running application and 2 VMs (Yellow boxes) running the function of router. My idea is that master VM (Yellow box) can translate IP address in VM (Blue box) as NAT function. I want that VM (Blue box) can send and receive data through master VM (Yellow box) router from outside (Internet).

How can I set this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Internet Access to a VirtualBox VM Using a VM Software Router**

I am still new here, but maybe this can point you in the right direction: First read [VirtualBox's explanation of networking interfaces and uses.](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

Also you did not specify what software router you have - so I will give an example using: [pfSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfsense)  (an open source software firewall/router).

SUMMARY:

Here is the example that follows network flow:

`Internet -> Host Machine -> Software Router -> VM Guest Machine`

For the Master Software Router (pfsense) you will need at least 2 network adapters:

- `Adapter 1 (NAT): Connect back to the Internet (WAN) & provide access for your hosts outside the internal network`
- `Adapter 2 (Internal Network): Provide connectivity for your Internal Network (LAN)`
- For the Master Router WAN interface we will use VirtualBox default NAT IP 10.0.2.15 /24
- For the Master Router LAN interface we will use IP 192.168.1.1 /24
- We are using a different IP network on LAN to separate this network from WAN and allow the Master Router to service LAN and avoid potential conflicts with VirtualBox's internal networks
- The LAN network can also have its own DHCP server to provide hosts on the internal network their own IPs.

For Ubuntu VM Network Settings:

- `Adapter 1 (Internal Network): Receive connectivity from Master Router internal LAN network`

Some more details:

For your Master Software Router you can use something like this in Virtualbox Networking Settings:

1. Network Adapter 1 tab: `Enabled Network Adapter attached to NAT`
2. Network Adapter 2 tab:

   - `Enabled Network Adapter attached to Internal Network`
   - `Enter a Name for your internal Network`

NOTES:

- Changing to static IP will require additional configurations to ensure the Master Router is communicating with the VirtualBox network and your Main network to resolve DNS and to access the Internet.
- Make sure that DHCP, DNS, NAT, etc. configured so can assign addresses to your LAN hosts & resolve DNS / internal addresses.
- Enable / change firewall rules to provide your network access to services and outside Internet
- Setup a LAN DHCP server - so your LAN hosts can receive IPs in your specified scope (IP range)

I had to shorten my answer -Said it looked like SPAM... but hope what I provided helps.

Comment: Hi @NoobNET14,
Your opinion is true in my case. I am sorry for not being clear! Master router running on VM is Click Modular Router.
But I am still confused that how ubuntu VM (Yellow box) can know its default gateway when you use internal mode between them. Becaue my main purpose is how to ping from client to outside network!
Thank you very much!